# How to localize selectOptions on the visual force page

Tags: localization, salesforce, visualforce

I am trying to localize selectOptions on the Visual Force page.

Here is the .class code snippet:

```
List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
List<MyOption__c> dropDownValues = [SELECT Id, Display_Label_Name__c FROM MyOption__c];
for (MyOption__c val : dropDownValues) {
    // Display_Label_Name__c field is the label from *.labels that needs to be translated
    options.add(new SelectOption(val.Id, val.Display_Label_Name__c));
}
```

Here is the .page code snippet:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!myVal}">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!options}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

Right now the dropdown displays the Display_Label_Name__c verbose. I am trying to see how I can display the translated version from the .labels file. Is it possible? If not, what's the work around?

Thank you for your responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All localisation of page text can be done with [Custom Labels](http://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/cl_about.htm).

1. Enable the translation workbench with the languages you require.
2. Create labels for all the localisible text on the page.
3. Replace the page text with the labels.
4. Add a [translation for each label](http://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/cl_translate_edit.htm).
5. Change your profile langauge to test.

But for your case you pull the select option text from a custom object. If the values of the select list are not expected to change frequently, less than once a week or so, then I would change to using custom labels.

Otherwise, you lose the value of Salesforce automatic language selection and have to implement something yourself.

I would recommend extending the custom object `MyOption__c` to have columns for all the supported languages. You could use an if/else block  or [dynamic apex](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) to select the select option text.

Sample using Dynamic Apex

```
string language = ParseForSupportedLangauges(UserInfo.getLanguage()); // includes __c

list<sobject> dropDownValues = Database.query('SELECT Id, '+language+' FROM MyOption__c');

for (sobject val : dropDownValues) {
    options.add(new SelectOption(val.get('Id'), val.get(language)));
}
```

`ParseForSupportedLangauges()` would be a custom method that checks for supported languages and assigns the default when necessary.

**EDIT**

Turns out there is a solution: Don't look for something until you need it, right?

Introduced in Spring '12 is the ability dynamicaly select the label to display suing array syntax. Also, the ability to create visualforce components from the controller was added but using the array syntax would be sufficient for your problem. This method would allow you to select the labels you want by using the query results from `MyOption__c`.

Using a repeat in visualforce to loop over the query results

```
<apex:repeat value="{!displayResultsValues}" var="labelName">
<apex:outputText value="{!$Label[labelName]}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

[Here is a good article to show the usage and syntax.](http://zachelrath.wordpress.com/2012/01/12/the-first-fruits-of-spring-12-dynamic-custom-label-retrieval/)

Comment: Hi Gerard, Thanks for the thorough reply! Our requirements are such that we need to be able to get the labels dynamically. Something similar to VF syntax: {!$Label[labelName]}. If no such thing exists in apex, your solution with adding a language column will be a good work around.

Comment: Hi @Gerard. That's my favorite article on the subject. Thanks for finding it. Unfortunately, the loop like that doesn't work for us because I need to display the label values in the selectOption tag: `<apex:selectOptions value="{!options}"/>`. So, there is no good way for me to tell VF that I need to treat the value of the selectOption as a label. So far your solution with adding a language column stands out as the best option.

Comment: I wish apex, as well as visual force, had this syntax `Label[labelName]`. At the moment, it's a platform limitation, which I didn't want to believe. Check this out: [link](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000714W)